# Shipping calculator state field change trigger update in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In the code below, I am trying to auto update the shipping calculator in WooCommerce cart page cart page when the selected state field is changed, to display shipping cost by state region:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'state_update_checkout', 50);
function state_update_checkout() {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("[name='calc_shipping_state']").on('change', function(e) {
    $("[name='calc_shopping']").trigger("click");
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

But it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @mujuonly this feature seems to be relative to checkout, but at cart page there is a button to click to update.

Comment: you are right. My mistake

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Update:** There are some mistakes in your code… Try the following instead:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'state_update_checkout', 50);
function state_update_checkout() {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            $(document.body).on('change', 'select[name="calc_shipping_state"]', function() {
                $(this).submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Update Woocommerce cart shipping methods on country change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307294/display-the-shipping-method-automatically-by-selecting-the-country-in-the-carts/63308700#63308700)