# Update Woocommerce cart shipping methods on country change

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Inspired by the question of: [update cart shipping woocommerce when change country with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424014/update-cart-shipping-woocommerce-when-change-country-with-ajax), (the answer does not work and is incorrect).

In my case I have 2 shipping Zones configured:

- Colombia - 3 shipping methods (Free, Pick up at Destination and Local Delivery)
- Rest of the World, I have a unique shipping method which is (Pick up at destination).

My intention is to hide the update button of the cart shipping calculator and that when selecting the shipping country the methods are automatically displayed.

**Note:** In the shipping calculator I only have the country activated, the other fields have been deactivated.  I have no knowledge of ajax  or jquery, but I think this is done with ajax / jquery. Please I appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the following:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'cart_country_update_shipping_methods', 50);
function cart_country_update_shipping_methods() {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) return; // On cart
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            $(document.body).on('change', 'select[name="calc_shipping_country"]', function(){
                $(this).submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Shipping calculator state field change trigger update in WooCommerce cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006414/shipping-calculator-state-field-change-trigger-update-in-woocommerce-cart/62009659#62009659)

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, by chance, do you know why it worked only once? If I select Colombia it works perfect but if I select another country it will not work again.

Comment: wow, too bad, if so then I won't be able to disable the refresh button, because if the customer makes a mistake, they won't be able to choose another option, just until they refresh the page.

Comment: It works great, but you still have to click somewhere inside or outside the selection field so that the script can be activated, the difference is that on the checkout page the script is more dynamic because it shows the methods immediately when selecting the country without clicking anywhere. In the same way, thank you very much, it is very good.

Comment: @Williams If you can upvote this one too https://stackoverflow.com/a/62009659/3730754 , It will be nice. Thanks.