# Shipping calculator auto update on country change in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I woulk like to calculate on Woocommerce shipping cost based on country without clicking "Update button".

I checked posts on forums but it did not work for me:
[Shipping calculator state field change trigger update in WooCommerce cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006414/shipping-calculator-state-field-change-trigger-update-in-woocommerce-cart)

Can someone help with it?

here is code I have right now:

```
// 1 Disable State
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_state', '__return_false' );
 
// 2 Disable City
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_city', '__return_false' );
 
// 3 Disable Postcode
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_postcode', '__return_false' );


add_action('wp_footer', 'cart_country_update_shipping_methods', 50);
function cart_country_update_shipping_methods() {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) return; // On cart
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            $(document.body).on('change', 'select[name="calc_shipping_country"]', function(){
                $(this).submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

[www.zGruzie.cz](http://www.zGruzie.cz) -- this web.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use Ajax if you want to update the shipping costs without clicking the update button. You can read more about it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710728/how-to-load-ajax-in-wordpress).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I am not familiar with Ajax, so I would appreciate if someone can help me edit code I pasted